# Linux cloning tools

Tags: linux, backup, clone, disk-image

Could you please advice how to clone CentOS with all installed software to another box.

What tools should be used?

Comment: Is the hardware identical, or different?  If so, how different is it?

Comment: Which release of CentOS do you want to clone?

Answer (score 4):

Couldn't you just clone the hard drive using a dd command and stick it into a new box?  Here is more on using dd: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DriveImaging

Comment: +1 for not mentioning things like clonezilla or others when `dd` is perfectly capable!

Answer (score 1):

I've used [PartImage](http://www.partimage.org/Main_Page) for things like that.

Answer (score 0):

While `dd` / `ddrescue` are great, it's a bit overkill if you have a huge drive and only a small part of it is used, how about just using `tar`? of course you will need to setup the bootloader by hand but that should be trivial.

Also check the [CentOS Migration Guide](http://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/MigrationGuide).

Comment: well there is a solution to this issue using `dd` as well. do a `dd if=/dev/zero of=/path/to/drive/zero.img;rm /path/to/drive/zero.img` Then when you're using dd to backup the drive, pipe it through `gzip` this will basically 'eliminate' all of the empty space as well as do great compression. This has the added benefit of cloning the whole HD and not needing to 'install' anything as well as using the smallest amount of space (for `dd`) possible.

Comment: The command `tar` will ignore hard-link. `rsync` is better.